# Move CentOS to new raid1 hardware server

Tags: linux, centos6, hardware-raid, raid1

I have an existed CentOS server with a normal hard disks (2 disks sda,sdb). They very small. Now I want to update server with a RAID1 hardware and new 2 bigger disks (remove 2 old disk). How can I do it? 
I have 2 idea:

1. Backup all data and reinstall OS (many things to reinstall such as webserver,mysql...)
2. Move OS to new disk by tools (how,which tools?)

Anybody has experience in this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's much wrong with JameZer's pointer (+1 from me!), but it does require some customisation (it deals with only a single system) and it's always nice to have something that spells out the basics here, instead of just pointing to an external resource.

For me, option (1) is cleaner, but it's a LOT of work, and will result in significant downtime.  Option (2) is less work, less downtime, and more normal.  I've done both in the past, and the key steps for option (2) in my experience are:

1. Update your current (source) C6 system to latest patchlevels.
2. Build the new (destination) chassis, and install a basic C6 server install on it.
3. Bring it up-to-patch.
4. Reboot the source system in single-user mode.
5. Reboot the destination system in rescue mode.
6. Bring the NICs up on both systems.
7. Using `tar` or similar tool, copy all the data, one partition at a time, from the source system to the destination.
8. Ensure that key files, eg `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-*`, are correct on the destination system.
9. Redoing `grub-install` on the destination can help avoid boot-time errors.

And generally, that's it.  There are doubtless other ways to accomplish your option (2), but that's the cookbook that's worked well for me in the recent past.  **You might wish to consider building a simple test source box in order to test this migration first** (you can still use the real destination hardware, since anything you do will be completely overwritten in the real migration).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This guide can help you install new disks, make raid and move the current installation to the raid drives. [Centos convert to RAID](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CentOS5ConvertToRAID)